# Scheduling SQL Server jobs at 2 AM and 2 PM every day

Tags: sql-server, scheduled-tasks

I want to schedule a job to run at 2AM and 2PM.

My current settings in **Job Schedule Properties** window of SQL Server:
[image]

**The question** is:

Should I set my **`Ending at`** to 2:00 PM or later eg. 3:00 PM, 11:50 PM or even 1:00 AM until a time before 2:00 PM ***(And in these cases, does SQL Server understand that I mean tomorrow?)***?

How the **`Ending at`** is important?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should create 2 planning time.

You make the first one occured every day (except perhaps weekend) and running at 2am.
You create another one running everyday at 2pm with the same kind.

I prefer that, cause personnaly my job should not work during week end.

Else you can of course do as you are doing, running every 12hours, starting at 2am.
The ending in your case is not important, it means if you wanna run something every 1 hour, it's between 7am to 4pm for example. As you are running every 12, you could do 2-2 or 2-3 it should be the same

Comment: Thank you for your advise, and specially thank you for the clarification in the last paragraph `:)`

Comment: Thanks again, I updated the question. I'd appreciate your answer.